# Cannot start React project

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I downloaded a project that I need to work on, but I can't run it using `yarn` or `npm`.

I have already tried updating dependencies and have also followed the steps in the error but nothing helped. Please help if anyone faced this problem.

Following are the screenshots of the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?`

Comment: even if node_modules exists the error is the same

Comment: Try "npm install" and then "npm start"

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the node_modules folder and package-lock.json then npm install and npm start again. i hope that will work